# Refresh image on the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to show JLabel with text and image GIF. When i call showLabel() method from Test class i see only text. I don't know how to refresh this image to show it. I read is problem with AWT in this case...

**Question: How to show this GIF image in my JLabel?**

LabelTest.class

```
public class LabelTest{

    private JWindow frame;
    private JLabel jLabel;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("PHOTO.gif");    

    public LabelTest() {
    }

    public void showLabel(String label) {
        frame = new JWindow();
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        frame.setContentPane(new TranslucentPane());
        frame.add(new JLabel(label, icon, JLabel.CENTER));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.paintAll(frame.getGraphics());
    }

    public void hideLabel() {
        frame.dispose();
    }
}
```

Test.class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        try {
            LabelTest p = new LabelTest();
            p.showLabel("I'M LABEL...");
            Thread.sleep(5000);     
            p.hideLabel();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

TranslucentPane.class

```
public class TranslucentPane extends JPanel {
    public TranslucentPane() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the program can't find the image; Where is `PHOTO.gif` located? If it's in the project's `src` folder, use `getClass().getResource("PHOTO.gif")`. If it's not somewhere inside your project you have to enter the full path to the image as the parameter. (e.g. `c:\\temp\\PHOTO.gif`)

Comment: There is no need for the `TranslucentPane` class. You haven't change any of the default behaviour of a JPanel. A JPanel is opaque by default. Get rid of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with LuxxMiner.
Most probably, the image can't be found.
To check the path you can use the following check:

```
public ImageIcon loadImageIconFromPath(String path) {
    URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So instead of:

```
frame.add(new JLabel(label, icon, JLabel.CENTER));
```

Try the following:

```
ImageIcon icon = loadImageIconFromPath("PHOTO.gif");    
if (icon != null)
    frame.add(new JLabel(label, icon, JLabel.CENTER));
else 
    frame.add(new JLabel("Missing image", JLabel.CENTER));
```